# Mongos router on single machine with multiple servers

Tags: mongodb, tomcat, server, webserver, sharding

I have problems to understand mongos routing for sharded clusters.
If i have a Server where i have ubuntu running and on the same machine a webserver and also a tomcat application server. Now both want to connect to a mongodb sharded cluster. 
Is the mongos instance running on the machine and it is possible to connect to it via php and java from both servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any number of client applications on a single host can connect to the sharded cluster through a single local mongos process.